# getting WGET to save clean file extensions, without query parameter

Tags: shell-script, wget, homebrew

I am using wget on mac to download hundreds of thousands of images...

however the saved files all have a '?' saved at the end of the file extension (like the start of a query parameter)

How can i get wget to download just the image with no weird characters?

this is what i am currently doing:

i have a bash script called list.sh which looks like this:

```
wget url -O filename.jpg 
wget url2 -O filename2.jpg
wget url3 -O filename3.jpg
```

i make it executable:

```
chmod 775 list.sh
```

then i run it

```
./list.sh
```

The downloaded files i get are:

```
filename.jpg?
filename2.jpg?
filename3.jpg?
```

It has been surprisingly difficult to remove the '?' from so many files, finder can't handle it.

I want to re-download the images with clean file names.

Any tips greatly apreciated

thanks

Matthew

Comment: Does your list of URLs have a `?` at the end of each one?

Comment: Did you create the script file on a Windows platform? Check for trailing CR/NL characters (and remove the wrong one)

Comment: thanks for your response. no i created it on macOS

Comment: the filenames in my source file are correct

Comment: I've just tried this on a Mac and I can reproduce the problem if I set the script filetype to DOS (i.e. a Windows sourced file). I used wget from Homebrew. Are you _sure_ that the filetype is native?

Comment: hi Roaima, thanks for your message. no, i am not sure it is native. how do i set or change that? i am also using wget from homebrew. i have create a text file on mac and made it executable

Comment: What does `file list.sh` return? Please put this in your question. Not as a comment. Make it easy for people to read all the relevant information in one place

Comment: thanks, i have now solved this by editing the downloaded files, see here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/721100/how-to-remove-query-parameters-from-file-extensions