# How to remove query parameters from file extensions?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, terminal

How to remove query parameters from file extensions

i have downloaded 260 000 image files, which look like this:

```
filename.jpg?
filename2.jpg?
filename3.jpg?
```

how can i easily rename/remove the offending '?' from the file extension?

i have tried various osx packages

```
Finder
A better Finder Rename 11
Name Mangler
Renamer
vRenamer
```

...but none of them can do the job

```
-most packages cannot seem to access the '?' in the file exenstion

-Name Mangler can suucesfuly append and extra ".jpg" to file, giving me filename3.jpg?.jpg 
i could work with this, but it also can only do 5000 files at a time, which means 50 batches :-/
```

It needs an efficient terminal command; any tips hugely appreciated!

thanks

Matthew

Comment: Do all your files have the `?` at the end of the filename?

Comment: yes they do ...

Comment: Is the `?` at the end of a filename something that only `ls` shows you (`ls` shows unprintable characters as `?`), or is it an actual literal question mark? What does `printf '%q\n' filename*.jpg*` print?

Comment: yes 'ls' shows the filename including the '?'

Comment: this command does not return any value:       printf '%q\n' filename*.jpg*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) with `bash`.

The below script will remove all `?` in the filename so if you had `file?name.jpg?` it will be replaced with `filename.jpg`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./*; do
   mv "file" "${file//\?/}"
done
```

or one-liner script:

```bash
for file in ./*; do mv "$file" "${file//\?/}" ; done
```

If you want to remove only the last character (which is `?`) you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./*; do 
mv "$file" "${file%?}" 
done
```

or one-liner script:

```bash
for file in ./*; do mv "$file" "${file%?}" ; done
```

**Note:** You should be placed in the directory where you have your files or you can replace `for file in ./*` to `for file in /path/to/your_working_directory/*`.

---

**Using rename**

You can easily rename your files by using `rename` command. I've seen that in macOS might no be installed so you should install with:

```bash
brew install rename
```

I'm not really sure if this command will work for macOS. I tested on Linux by using `file-rename` and as far as I know both are the same. If I am wrong, please let me now.

This script will remove the `?` at the end of every filename:

```bash
rename 's/\?$//' *
#or
rename 's/\?$//' /path/to/your_working_directory/*
```

And this will remove all `?` of every filename:

```bash
rename 's/\?//g' *
#or
rename 's/\?//g' /path/to/your_working_directory/*
```

Comment: Thank you Edgar!!!!    i really appreciated your help, you have solved the problem. i am using this:   for file in ./*; do mv "$file" "${file%?}" ; done